# Apache Flume POC issues

Tags: logging, log4j, flume

Currently I am working on a POC to collect the logs from our web application servers through Apache Flume container and flume-ng-log4jappender client. Everything is working fine in Tomcat instances but facing issues while integrating with Websphere due to JDK mismatch because my local Websphere is running on JDK 1.5.

Can you pls. tell me if there is any client java program to submit messages to Flume on JDK 1.5 environment. Appreciate quick your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flume's spooling directory source.

Write your log entries to a file. Roll them on occasion and put them in a spool dir for the Flume source to read.

The log4j appender will cause your application to fail if it cannot push the events to Flume.